# Print a figure with 8 subfigures without shaving some subfigures overlap and not show full content

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats

I have a figure with is made of 8 subfigures: 4 subfigures on the top and 4 subfigures on the bottom. The problem is that the end of the x axis is not always visible as some subfigures overlap with others and stop the end of the x axis from being printed as shown in the following screenshot. How to fix that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,sigconf,review,anonymous]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%%
%% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs
% \AtBeginDocument{%
%   \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
%     \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

%\acmYear{2020}\copyrightyear{2020}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
%\acmConference[ICSSP '20]{International Conference on Software and Systems Process}{May 23--24, 2020}{Seoul, Republic of Korea}
%\acmBooktitle{International Conference on Software and Systems Process (ICSSP '20), May 23--24, 2020, Seoul, Republic of Korea}
%\acmPrice{15.00}
%\acmDOI{10.1145/3379177.3388900}
%\acmISBN{978-1-4503-7512-2/20/05}


%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
%\usepackage{cite}

%\usepackage[textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
% \newcommand{\cmd}[1]{{\color{blue}CMD:  {#1}}}%
 %\newcommand{\mh}[1]{{\color{red}MH: {#1}}}%
 %\newcommand{\ae}[1]{{\color{orange}AE: {#1}}}%

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx, ragged2e}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

\title{test}
\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Precision \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{TracePrecisionTError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Precision \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{NoTracePrecisionTError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Recall \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{TraceRecallTError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Recall \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{NoTraceRecallTError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill

\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Precision \% versus N$\rightarrow$T errors Seeding}
\label{TracePrecisionNError}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Precision \% versus N$\rightarrow$T errors Seeding}
\label{NoTracePrecisionNError}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Recall \% versus N$\rightarrow$T errors Seeding}
\label{TraceRecallNError}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Recall \% versus N$\rightarrow$T errors Seeding}
\label{NoTraceRecallNError}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{T trace/N trace Precision/Recall when seeding T$\rightarrow$N/N$\rightarrow$T errors}
\label{PrecisionRecall}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

here is the example image

[image]

Comment: please  include the code inline in the question (you can use `example-image` as the image. The question is archived here forever and will not make sense if you change the code at that link (and many people will not follow external links anyway)

Comment: also note that overleaf is showing 4 errors after _any_ error don't even look at the generated pdf it is at best usable for debugging, Please post an error free document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I just did can you help me?

Comment: I meant use `example-image` but OK, thanks, Note never do `[width=5cm,height=4cm]` as that will distort the image, only specify height or width, also just specify a width that will fit so `[width=\linewidth]` so it fits into your subfigure

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Command \`\Bbbk' already defined.` and `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.`

Comment: You should add `\hfill` commands also on the lower 4 subfigures!

Answer (score 2):

Once I had deleted all the spurious package calls so that the example runs without error:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass[xcolor=table,sigconf,review,anonymous]{acmart}



\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\title{test}
\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Precision \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{TracePrecisionTError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Precision \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{NoTracePrecisionTError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Recall \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{TraceRecallTError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Recall \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{NoTraceRecallTError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill

\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Precision \% versus N$\rightarrow$T errors Seeding}
\label{TracePrecisionNError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Precision \% versus N$\rightarrow$T errors Seeding}
\label{NoTracePrecisionNError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Recall \% versus N$\rightarrow$T errors Seeding}
\label{TraceRecallNError}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Recall \% versus N$\rightarrow$T errors Seeding}
\label{NoTraceRecallNError}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{T trace/N trace Precision/Recall when seeding T$\rightarrow$N/N$\rightarrow$T errors}
\label{PrecisionRecall}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

then you get

```
Overfull \hbox (20.7502pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 64--65
```

multiple times as a 5cm wide image does not fit in the space you have specified.
That accounts for the over-printing.

In addition you should not specify height and width or it will distort the image, just specify one or the other. Here `width=\linewidth` will make it fit the sub-figures.

Changing all instances of `[width=5cm,height=4cm]` to `[width=\linewidth]` lets it run with no overfull box warnings.

Comment: Same comment as in the question above: You should add `\hfill` commands also on the lower 4 subfigures, so that the images are equally distributed on the upper and the lower part.

Comment: @Nico I only looked at the log not the output or input:-) will fix, thanks:-)

Comment: You are welcome :)